# How can I print a path with a home directory replaced by ~ in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

How can I print a path in Terminal with the home folder path replaced by a ~?

```
pwd
/Users/denz/projects/coolApp
```

But I want to something like this

```
~/projects/coolApp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function:

```
pwdr () {
  pwd | sed s,$HOME,~,
}
```

Add this function to a profile file and use `pwdr`.

---

In `bash` you can also use parameter expansion and avoid the call to `sed` by using the rather magically looking

```
echo ${PWD/~/\~}
```

The `${...}` expression can be used anywhere a shell variable can be used as well, the `echo` is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Of course this may fail in corner cases, like if there is a directory called `/Users/denz/foo/Users/denz` which this would translate to `~/foo/~`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Made a small change to the `sed` way, the corner case should work ok now with both options.